# Apache2: Trying to map a subdomain to a subdirectory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, cname-record

So basically I want to have:
sub.domain.com/*anything* -> domain.com/asub/*anything*

I'm a bit new to this and a bit confused. The first thing I did was configure my DNS settings so sub.domain.com goes to domain.com using a CNAME (would an A record and the IP be better?)

Next I went into my VirtualHost file and have:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.com/asub/$1 [R]
```

So the first rule is meant to handle www. and making sure that is caught correctly and it works.

The second rule is what I've added for the subdomain mapping and it doesn't seem to be doing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have access to the apache configuration, I would advise you to use separate vhosts; this prevents looping in your rewrites/redirects.

You must also escape any special characters in a matching pattern.
And anchor your patterns properly!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias sub.example.com

  RewriteEngine on
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/asub/$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The comment is deliberate; depending on whether you want www. or sub. to be matched for any request not covered here, comment out the other one and it will be the default for anythingelse.example.com.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Just one other question. Is there any way to keep the url with the subdomain without doing a webredirect or something like that?

Comment: Not without using a proxy.